# How do I update column values to equal column values based on another column?

Tags: php, sql

I have a sql table like this,

```
+-------+-------+-----+
| name  | start | end |
+-------+-------+-----+
| Joe   |    14 |   - |
| Joe   |    13 |   - |
| Steve |    11 |   - |
| Steve |    15 |   - |
| Bruce |    10 |   - |
+-------+-------+-----+
```

and i want to update the values for column "end" with the values from "start" for each unique column value "name", so it looks like this.

```
+-------+-------+-----+
| name  | start | end |
+-------+-------+-----+
| Joe   |    14 |  14 |
| Joe   |    13 |  13 |
| Steve |    11 |  11 |
| Steve |    15 |  15 |
| Bruce |    10 |  10 |
+-------+-------+-----+
```

my question is: how do i do this in SQL code, and how would it look like with a PHP mysql query?

Comment: `UPDATE yourTable SET end = start` ?

Comment: What do you mean by _'for each unique column value "name"'_ ...? Your desired result simply appears to have `end` set to the value of `start` for each row, regardless of _anything else_. So `UPDATE table SET end = start` should do the trick ...?

Comment: but what if i have distinct values for column "start"? UPDATE table SET end=start would only work if column start is the same. if column name"joe" has two values for "start", your proposition would take the first value and fill "end" with it.

Comment: @MartinKuchen It will still work. See the fiddle in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should do. Even in cases where there are multiple values.

```
UPDATE    TableName
SET       End = Start
```

See here -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/465c22/1